# why did my ajax not submitting?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have now problem with ajax sending form and couldnt find where is the error,

here my html:

```
<form method="post" id="update-profile" name="update-form" action="process.php">

<input name="username" type="text"  id="username"  value="<?php echo $username;?>"/>
........
 <input name="update_profile" type="button" class="submit" id="update_profile" value="Update" onclick="return formValidation();" />
```

and this is my javascript :

```
    function formValidation() {
        // other validations here
    if (validsex(umsex, ufsex)) { 



          $('#mydata').html('Saving ...<img src="../images/loading.gif" />');
      $.ajax({

      url: "process.php",
      dataType: 'json' ,
      data :{    id       : document.getElementById('iidd').value,
                 username : document.getElementById('username').value,
                 name     : document.getElementById('name').value,
                   password : document.getElementById('password').value,
                    slist: document.getElementById('slist').value,
                  sexs : sexs,
                  update_profile : "update_profile",




     type : 'POST',

      success: function(msg){


       $('#mydata').html("<span >saved succefully </span>").delay(3000).fadeOut('fast');


       }
         }


           });


                         }
                    }

            }
        }

}
return false;
  }
```

have even debugged with this

```
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
   },
```

and it said : `AJAX error: undefined : undefined`

so i dont know what the problem.

here my process.php :

```
   if (isset($_POST['update_profile'])) {

    $id = $_POST['iidd'];
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['slist']);
    $sex = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sexs']);
 //update query here
```

thanks!.

Comment: there is problem with braces

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems you are sending `id` in the Javascript, but then in the PHP you are checking for `$_POST['iidd']`?

Comment: @autibyte look my comment please to sushanth . i edited your suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i have fixed it .

after making missing brace which @sushanth said and  changed this `$id = $_POST['id']` after that it was the success message.

i have done this in my server side

```
     $response_array['status'] = 'success';
    }else {$response_array['status'] = 'error';}
    echo json_encode($response_array);
```

and the in client side this:

```
    success: function(data){
       if(data.status == 'success')
    //   jAlert("Your data is saved succefully");
$('#mydata').html("<span >saved succefully!</span>").delay(3000).fadeOut('fast');
   else if(data.status == 'error')
      alert("Error on query!");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not closed the braces for `data` property

```
     data: {
             id: document.getElementById('iidd').value,
             username: document.getElementById('username').value,
             name: document.getElementById('name').value,
             password: document.getElementById('password').value,
             slist: document.getElementById('slist').value,
             sexs: sexs,
             update_profile: "update_profile"

         }, <---- Missing this
```

And I do not understand the reason for all the other extra braces in your code.

Supposed to look like

```
 function formValidation() {
     // other validations here
     if (validsex(umsex, ufsex)) {
         $('#mydata').html('Saving ...<img src="../images/loading.gif" />');
         $.ajax({

             url: "process.php",
             dataType: 'json',
             data: {
                 id: document.getElementById('iidd').value,
                 username: document.getElementById('username').value,
                 name: document.getElementById('name').value,
                 password: document.getElementById('password').value,
                 slist: document.getElementById('slist').value,
                 sexs: sexs,
                 update_profile: "update_profile"
             },
             type: 'POST',
             success: function (msg) {
                 $('#mydata')
                     .html("<span >saved succefully </span>")
                     .delay(3000).fadeOut('fast');
             }

         });
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: have done the brace which was missing and edited also what autibyte to `$id = $_POST['id'];` to check for id . and the other braces are as i said for other checking functions so they are right. But it still dont update database. In console with this error function im getting this `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"\r\nupdated","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

profile-update.js (line 44)

AJAX error: parsererror : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character`

Comment: i have removed this function of error , and the database is updated , but i didnt get the success message nor this loading gif didnt hide.

Comment: @autibyte you mean in this second comment ? yes im selecting `mydata` and it shows the loading gif so it means it works , but after updating it does nt show the success message nor this loading gif will not hide. it stays loading

Comment: Update the question with `json` dump that would come from the server.. Looks like there are errors in your `JSON`